# Progress not displayed in Github contribution chart?

Tags: git, github

My repository in github is public. When I am pushing files from my local system through command line to github, the new contributions are not shown in the contribution Histogram.

But when I add any file directly into my repository in github the contribution is shown in the histogram.
What is the reason for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible reason is when you are pushing from another branch than master:

Only contribution done in the master branch of a repo you own are shown.

Answer (score 2):

Same happened with me, probably you should set your global email address correctly. This can be done through the command line, use below command replacing your email address used on GitHub. Detailed help available [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/)

```
git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
```

OR

If you are using GitHub Desktop, make sure your email address is correct.

> File -> Options -> Git -> Email