# User joined to github before github founded

Tags: github

How this possible that user joined to Github before Github founded.

[image]

Okay but Github founded in 2008.How this is possible that user joined in 1998?

[User link](https://github.com/mihaip)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git history can be imported from other version control tools, which have existed since before GitHub ([or Git, for that matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git#Releases)) were created. The timestamps on the changes can be preserved to point to the original time the commit was made using, say, SVN, instead of the timestamp of the import from SVN to Git.

The oldest commit from [the user in the screenshot](https://github.com/mihaip/): https://github.com/mihaip/mscape/commit/7e22d91396b8a73dbdea4cfc44e8630072069199

As per the MScape website, all this software is defunct: https://www.mscape.com/

Comment: For that matter, it could have been a Git repo prior to the existence GitHub and then imported to GitHub, or the date could have been manually dated in Git.  There's a number of similar reasons why the timestamps in Git history could predate GitHub.

Comment: @M.Justin that was my first assumption. In this case, Git wasn't released until 2005, so these commits would likely have not originated from Git unless [the date on the timestamp was explicitly overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23609991/139010) - totally possible, but unlikely in this case, given that this repo is an archive of old software.